# I want to connect to data but I can't. How do I fix it? #Postgres

Tags: postgresql

[image]

I want to connect to data but I can't. How do I fix it? The information shows up like a picture I sent for you to see.

Answer (score 1):

You have to upgrade the PostgreSQL client software employed by the unnamed program you are using to a later version that supports the `scram-sha-256` authentication method introduced in PostgreSQL v10.

Downgrading `password_encryption` in PostgreSQL to `md5`, changing all the passwords and using the `md5` authentication method is a possible, but bad alternative. It is more effort, and you get worse security and old, buggy software.

Comment: I'm currently using PostgreSQL v14, which means it's too new?

Comment: No, that is fine. Your client is too old. That's what you should upgrade.

Comment: The program developer has stopped upgrading the program, is there any other way to suggest?

Comment: My answer has an alternative solution. But you should stop using that software.

Comment: I don't want to use but forced to use

Comment: @parkker Many clients just link to a shared library (like libpq) and that library can be upgraded instead of the client itself.